# How to create tables with "models.py" in the main folder where "settings.py" is in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-migrations

I'm trying to create a table with `models.py` in the main folder `core` where `settings.py` is as shown below:

```
django-project
|-core
|  |-models.py # Here
|  └-settings.py
|-app1
└-app2
```

This is `models.py` below:

```py
# "core/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Then, I tried to make migrations as shown below below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

But, I couldn't make migrations getting the message below:

> No changes detected

So, how can I create a table with `models.py` in the main folder `core`?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to set `"core"` to [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps) in `settings.py` as shown below. *If not assigning `"core"` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, you cannot make migrations in the main folder `core`:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "core"
]
```

Then, you need to make migrations by specifying the main folder `core` as shown below. *If not specifying the main folder `core`, you cannot make migrations in the main folder `core`:

```
                               # ↓ Here
python manage.py makemigrations core
```

Then, `migrations` folder with `__init__.py` and `0001_initial.py` is made as shown below:

```
django-project
|-core
|  |-models.py
|  |-settings.py
|  └-migrations # Here
|     |-__init__.py # Here
|     └-0001_initial.py # Here
|-app1
└-app2
```

Finally, you need to migrate to create a table as shown below. *You don't need to specify the main folder name `core`:

```py
python manage.py migrate
```

In addition, you can check if the table is really created or not by creating `admin.py` in `core` folder as shown below:

```py
# "core/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, the table is really created as shown below:

[image]